# What SVG element can i use to replace LinearGradient and keep all the same drawn regions.

Tags: svg, react-native

I am currently working on a modified version of [react-native-circular-slider](https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-slider) and i am looking to replace the LinearGradient used for the dial wheel with something that i can just apply a flat color and transparency to.

I am not familiar with SVG and i have already tried putting in Line and Circle and cant seem to get it to work.

Code Snippet that runs the wheel:

```
<Defs>
        {   
          range(segments).map(i => {
            const { fromX, fromY, toX, toY } = calculateArcCircle(i, segments, radius, startAngle, angleLength);
            const { fromColor, toColor } = calculateArcColor(i, segments, gradientColorFrom, gradientColorTo)
            return (
              <LinearGradient key={i} id={getGradientId(i)} x1={fromX.toFixed(2)} y1={fromY.toFixed(2)} x2={toX.toFixed(2)} y2={toY.toFixed(2)}>
                <Stop offset="0%" stopColor={toColor} />
                <Stop offset="1" stopColor={toColor} />
              </LinearGradient>
            )
          })   
        }
</Defs>
```

segments would just be a number such as 5 or 10,
i have tried plugging fromX -> toY into a line and it didnt work for me(could just be doing it wrong) any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was quite simple. I used a path and iterated through it the same way the linear gradient did.

Code sample(with adjustments for opacity and color):

```
range(segments).map(i => {
            const { fromX, fromY, toX, toY } = calculateArcCircle(i, segments, radius, startAngle, angleLength);
            const d = `M ${fromX.toFixed(2)} ${fromY.toFixed(2)} A ${radius} ${radius} 0 0 1 ${toX.toFixed(2)} ${toY.toFixed(2)}`;

            return (
              <Path
                d={d}
                key={i}
                strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
                stroke={"#133954"} // used to be `url(#${getGradientId(i)})`
                strokeOpacity={.7}
                fill="transparent"
              />
            )
          })
```